# Unexpected $var (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I want to write an easy battle in php between two characters (classes). This is my code:

```
class Characters
{
    public $hp = rand(int,int);
    public $attack = rand(int,int);
};

class You extends Characters
{
    $hp = rand(10,20); //this is line 11
    $attack = rand(2,10);
};

$player = new You;

echo $hp;
```

But the terminal is throws: 'unexpected $hp (T_VARIABLE) in /home/szigeti/Desktop/sublime/Game/Gameboard/index.php on line 11'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the variable scope in your class `You`,

Change,

```
class You extends Characters
{
    $hp = rand(10,20); //this is line 11
    $attack = rand(2,10);
};
```

to,

```
class You extends Characters
{
    public $hp = rand(10,20); //this is line 11
    public $attack = rand(2,10);
};
```

Also, when calling a class variable you need to refer to the object that is referring to it,

Change,

```
$player = new You;

echo $hp;
```

to,

```
$player = new You;

echo $player->hp;
```

**Reading Material**

Please read up on PHP OOP from the official documentation to prevent future mistakes.

[PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: @DanielSzigeti if the answer helped, please accept it.